# Why NServiceBus.NHibernate causes CodeAnalysis warning regarding Common.Logging reference?

Tags: nservicebus, common.logging

I have an NServiceBus endpoint configured to UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister.

I use EL 5 for logging:

```
<section name="loggingConfiguration"  type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

I also added a reference in the project to the NServiceBus.Core.

Why do I get the following CodeAnalysis warning:

Warning 36 CA0060 : The indirectly-referenced assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: c:\NServicebus3.3.2\NServiceBus.NHibernate.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Common.Logging v2, you can get that from nuget using the following:

```
PM> Install-Package Common.Logging -Version 2.0
```